# Checking Whether a Task Has Succeeded Before Timer Expires C# (Multi-thread)

Tags: c#, multithreading, timertask

I have a scenario in which a parent thread spawns multiple task/job threads (done by someone else). At the end, I need to perform one additional task which is unrelated to the job threads.

What I need is to execute this new task (checking for existance of a file on a remove server) for as long as a fixed time, i.e. 30 minutes max, and to repeat the process in a fixed interval, i.e. every 2 minutes, until the condition is satisfied. If the confirmation is succeeded, it should exit back to the main thread (parent -- parent thread needs to wait for this particular task to conclude before terminating).

I am very new to C# multi-threading, if even we need threading for this case. So, can somebody give me a guidance.

```
Main thread
{
Child threads0...n
All Done

For as long as n minutes
(R) Every m minute, check for something
If succeed, exit
If not, continue waiting for m minute, then (R)
}
```

Comment: I'd advise against inventing a new programming language just for the purposes of telling us what you're trying to do. It isn't very clear.

Comment: Possibly duplicate with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771364/best-method-to-block-until-certain-condition-is-met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
     while (!CheckForSomething())
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

  }).Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

Comment: Thank you dmg, and I apologize for not bringing this to the attention sooner, but I am running this against .NET 4.0, not 4.5 (Task.Delay() is not in .NET 4.0).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, not listed exausted here, :)

- Use AutoResetEvent, [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx).
- Use Task.ContinueWith, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) and [this example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500398/c-sharp-mixed-use-of-task-and-dispatcher-invoke-why-it-halts).
- Use [Paralle.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx)
- And other low level ones such as the use of lock etc.